# I got infinite loop issues in c++ beginner

Tags: c++

Fairly new with programming was wondering if you could help. Got an infinite loop with my code

```
int main()
{
int age, finalMark;

cout << "enter age: ";
cin >> age;
cout << "enter mark: ";
cin >> finalMark;

while (age != 0)
{
    if(age < 30 && finalMark > 65)
    cout << "You are the an ideal candidate" << endl;

    else
        cout << "You are not the ideal candidate. Goodbye" << endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

any help would be appreciate, sorry if its very basic/easy to solve

Comment: Whats the loop supposed to do?

Comment: How do you expect `age` to change during the execution of the loop? Read the code back to yourself and remind yourself what it does.

Comment: You need to use break in your loop or use do, while loop and take input from user inside loop.

Comment: What's the old saying "If your not the lead dog, the scenery never changes?".... same applies to `age` in your loop `:)`

Comment: The `age` variable never changes inside the `while` loop, so it will never exit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a loop, make sure that the condition isn't true at some point, otherwise, you end up with an endless loop.

Here if the value of age is initially different from 0, then you'll never break out of the loop, because you don't change it anywhere within the loop.

```
while (age != 0)
{
   if(age < 30 && finalMark > 65)
        cout << "You are the an ideal candidate" << endl;

    else
        cout << "You are not the ideal candidate. Goodbye" << endl;
}
```

If you want to simply check a condition, and do something depending on its outcome only once, use an "if" statement:

```
if (age != 0)
{
   if(age < 30 && finalMark > 65)
       cout << "You are the an ideal candidate" << endl;

   else
       cout << "You are not the ideal candidate. Goodbye" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Got it. Make the loop stop somehow. I see now using the while was a silly there...Thanks!:-)

Comment: @KeánThompson If an answer solved your problem, the proper way to show that and thank the answerer is to [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) instead of posting a "thanks" comment.